# How to replace all other symbols besides digits beside whitespace and newline using regex python3

Tags: python-3.x, regex, io, with-statement, regexp-replace

So, I have a file and I am doing this as an assignment. I have firstly replaced all digits with 0 and than all letters with 1. After that, I should replace all other symbols with 2 which I have done but I would like to keep the whitespaces and newline. Here is the code:

```
import re

ulaz = input("Unesite ime fajla:")
izlaz = input("Unesite ime fajla:")

with open(ulaz) as existing_file:
    text = existing_file.read()
    text = re.sub(r'[0-9]', '0', text)
    text = re.sub(r'[A-Za-z]', '1', text)
    text = re.sub(r'\D', '2', text)
    print(text)

    with open(izlaz, "w") as file_new:
        file_new.write(text)
```

As you can see, I am reading from one file and writing to another. The last re.sub replaces all including whitespace and newline. I have searched for an answer but didn't find a one that changes all other symbols not including digits, whitespaces and newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final regex replacement looks off to me, because at that point "all other symbols" should be defined as anything other than 0 or 1 (or whitespace, which you also want to retain).  Consider this slightly modified version:

```
text = existing_file.read()
text = re.sub(r'[0-9]', '0', text)
text = re.sub(r'[A-Za-z]', '1', text)
text = re.sub(r'[^01\s]', '2', text)
```

Comment: Thanks but I had to remove the + sign in all three rows because a plus sign would give me one digit for an entire word and not per character and so on.